# Localhosted APIs are not working in UWP unity build

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, localhost

I am making an app in my unity application server is locally hosted, all APIs are are working in exe build but in case of UWP build APIs are not working, I have searched about it but not got solution .

I have tried with http and https dummy APIs hosted on internet that are working fine and I got response, but locally hosted are not working.